# JS - Create object shorthand

Tags: javascript, syntax, shorthand

Take the below object:

```
var value = 'bar';
var obj = { foo: value }
// -> Object { foo="bar" }
```

Supposing the key was also a variable, one could go:

```
var key = 'foo', value = 'bar';
var obj = {}
obj[key] = value;
// -> Object { foo="bar" }
```

Now, I want to do this in one line (shorthand). So I tried:

```
var obj = {}[key] = value; // or,
var obj = ({})[key] = value; // or,
var obj = new Object()[key] = value;
// -> "bar"
```

This oddly produces a String instead of an Object.

Is there any way to do this shorthand?

Comment: No, there isn't, and why would there be !

Comment: Same reason I would use {} instead of new Object(). It's just cleaner in some instances.

Comment: how `var obj = new Object()[key] = value;` is better than `var obj = {}; obj[key] = value;`?

Comment: ES6 only `obj = {[key]: value}`

Comment: None of your attempts are cleaner than simply typing it out on two lines...

Comment: @meagar I agree 100%, I hope the OP doesn't start using one of the suggested answers that also aren't very readable

Comment: It's sad that the only correct answer was downvoted and deleted. Outside of ES6, there **is no shorthand for this**. All the answers are horrible, and not a "shorthand" by any sane definition. Do you seriously think `var obj = (function(o) {o[key]=value; return o})({});` is a good **shorthand** for `var obj = {}; obj[key] = value`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ECMAScript 6 will allow you to do

```
var obj = {
    [key]: value
};
```

[Browser support](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#object_literal_extensions) is not great yet, but transpilers such as [6to5](https://6to5.org) allow you to use this notation today!

Comment: Looking forward to it :)

Answer (score 6):

You can, or almost can. If you put the creation of the object, and its assignment to `obj` in parentheses, you can set a property of the result of that expression:

```js
var obj, key='foo', value = 'bar';
(obj = {})[key] = value;

alert(obj);  // [object Object]
alert(obj.foo);  // bar
```

The `var` keyword cannot be included in that expression within parentheses, so either you will have to declare obj before (like I did), or not declare it at all and accept that it will be in global scope.

Comment: This is more what I was looking for.

Comment: Nice, but it relies on assignment returning the assigned value, I  don't think I would ever use it in production, but it's clever golfing.

Comment: Can't get any cleaner than that.

Comment: Isn't this two lines?

Comment: It does rely on assignments returning the assigned value, but I don't think that's a "but". This fenomenon is used a lot in production code, although maybe not in a case like this. But what about code like `while (element = element.getNextSibling()) { doSomethingWith(element); }`?

Comment: Um, I just tried this in a browser console, and it also returned a string like in my example. Anyone else test it?

Comment: That's because in my snippet, I alerted the `foo` property of the object instead of the object itself. I wanted to show that it is an actual object and that the assignment of the property also worked. I changed it to two alerts now. Tested and works in IE 11 and Chrome 39.

Comment: @dc2 This isn't cleaner, if anything this is just obfuscating your code! Don't use this, or *any of the answers here*. Slamming a bunch of things onto one line is not a desirable goal in and of itself. Your need to focus on writing *readable* code, not writing *short* code. All of these answers are technically correct, but universally horrible. Any developer reviewing your code is going to tell you to *fix* any such instances. If I ever encountered `(obj = {})[key] = value;` I would immediately strip it out, `git blame` it, and tell the person responsible never to do it again.

Comment: @meager I agree. For academic purposes it is nice to solve such a puzzle and it will teach you valuable lessons about how JavaScript evaluates complex expressions. Whether to use it in production is up to dc2. I admit, I wouldn't use this in production either and just use more lines of code until ECMA6 would be available in every browser I would like to support.

Comment: @meagar tracking :) don't worry - there won't be any cataclysmic upheavals due to answers posted here. I was simply curious.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what you call a *one-liner*, with some code golf you can do

```
var obj = (function(o) {o[key]=value; return o})({});
```

it think that's the shortest you'll get it ?

Comment: @Hristo That is an empty object being passed into the anonymous function that is immediately executed

Comment: I'm still trying to understand... The function expression is executed immediately and returns an object.  Intuitively I suppose that the empty object {} in the parentheses at the end ({}) will be prozessed as parameter for the function(o).  Is that correct?  I just don't get the relation of ({}) on the right and the anonymous function expression (function(o){...}) on the left?!

Comment: @Hristo - Maybe it's clearer if you break it up -> **http://jsfiddle.net/puk7kafy/**

Comment: No, the part about the empty object was clear... but a function definition like function(){}() I can't understand...  Normally it shall be defined just like function(){} ... Please give me a reference for the second pair of parentheses - what do they and if this definition can be used in some other context?

Comment: @Hristo If you name the function and break it up,  it should clarify that the empty object is being passed into the function `function create(o) {o[key]=value; return o};` Now use it like `var obj = create({})`' Then if you work your way back and inline the `create` function, it should see what is happening, you just need to realize that there are parentheses around the function.

Answer (score 3):

Something like that [is coming in ECMAScript 6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer):

> With ECMAScript 6, there is a shorter notation available to achieve
>   the same:
>
> ```
> var a = "foo", 
>     b = 42, 
>     c = {};
>
> // Shorthand property names (ES6) 
> var o = { a, b, c };
> ```

So you could create your object with the following code

```
var foo = 'bar';
var obj = {foo};
```

Answer (score 0):

No shorthand in ECMAScript 5 (the current version), but you can make a method

```
function createObject(key, value /*, key, value, ... */ ) {
    var object = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i = i + 2) {
        object[arguments[i]] = arguments[i+1];
    }
    return object;
}
```

Then you can call it like this

```
var obj = createObject(key, value, 'anotherKey', 'anotherVal');
```

Comment: Isn't this eight lines? ;-)

Comment: One line every time you call it.